# xcodebuild arch i386 sdk iphonesimulator7.1 errors

Tags: xcode

For users having trouble building cordova/phonegap apps to send to Facebook for review of permissions using the following command:

```
xcodebuild arch i386 sdk iphonesimulator7.1
```

and getting errors like:

```
file not found #import ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

Follow these instructions:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/creating-ios-simulator-build-for-review

Use this command to build your app

```
xcodebuild -project HelloWorld.xcodeproj -arch i386 -target HelloWorld -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator clean build VALID_ARCHS=i386 CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/pedro/Documents/Cordova/HelloWorld/platforms/ios/build
```

If you want to read more about it, I found the solution here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/oclint-users/GD1a242k_X0